# Application keeps crashing when I try to load the database

Tags: java, android

I'm currently making an android application and now I'm trying to add this new "listingStatus" column to my database, I added the column name to my onCreate() function but I still keep getting this is my logCat.
Any ideas how to solve this issue? I've tried dropping my database and recreating it but I keep getting the same error.

```
package com.example.shareandcare;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class listingHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public listingHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, "listing.db", null, 2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table listing(_id integer primary key autoincrement, listingTitle text, listingTag text, listingDescription text, listingDimensionX float, listingDimensionY float, listingDimensionZ float, listingImage text, listingStatus text)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
        db.execSQL("drop table if exists listing");
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public Cursor getAll() {
        return (getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("select _id, listingTitle, listingTag, listingDescription, listingDimensionX, listingDimensionY, listingDimensionZ, listingImage from listing order by listingTag", null));
    }

    public Cursor getAllConfirmed() {
        String arg = "1";
        String[] args = {arg};
        return (getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("select _id, listingTitle, listingTag, listingDescription, listingDimensionX, listingDimensionY, listingDimensionZ, listingImage from listing where listingStatus=?", args));
    }

    public Cursor getById(String id) {
        String[] args = {id};

        return (getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("select _id, listingTitle, listingTag, listingDescription, lisitngDimensionX, listingDimensionY, listingDimensionZ, listingImage from listing where _id=?", args));
    }

    public Cursor getByTitle(String title) {
        String[] args = {title};

        return (getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("select _id, listingTitle, listingTag, listingDescription, listingDimensionX, listingDimensionY, listingDimensionZ, listingImage from listing where listingTitle =?", args));
    }

    public Cursor getByTag(String tag) {
        tag = tag.toLowerCase();
        String[] args = {tag};

        return (getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("select _id, listingTitle, listingTag, listingDescription, listingDimensionX, listingDimensionY, lisitngDimensionZ, listingImage from listing where listingTag =?", args));
    }

    public void updateListingStatus(String title) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        String[] args ={title};

        cv.put("listingStatus", "1");
        getWritableDatabase().update("listing", cv, "title=?", args);
    }

    public void addListing(String listingTitle, String listingTag, String listingDescription, String listingDimensionX, String listingDimensionY, String listingDimensionZ, String listingImage) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        cv.put("listingTitle", listingTitle);
        cv.put("listingTag", listingTag.toLowerCase());
        cv.put("listingDescription", listingDescription);
        cv.put("listingDimensionX", listingDimensionX);
        cv.put("listingDimensionY", listingDimensionY);
        cv.put("listingDimensionZ", listingDimensionZ);
        cv.put("listingImage", listingImage);

        getWritableDatabase().insert("listing", "listingTitle", cv);
    }

    public void delete(String id) {
        String[] args = {id};
        getWritableDatabase().delete("listing","_id=?", args);
    }

    public void resetDatabase() {
        getWritableDatabase().execSQL("drop table if exists listing");
    }
}
```

Here's my logCat.

```
    --------- beginning of crash
2020-02-10 00:24:06.786 12602-12602/com.example.shareandcare E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.shareandcare, PID: 12602
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.shareandcare/com.example.shareandcare.admin}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: listingStatus (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: select _id, listingTitle, listingTag, listingDescription, listingDimensionX, listingDimensionY, listingDimensionZ, listingImage from listing where listingStatus=1
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: listingStatus (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: select _id, listingTitle, listingTag, listingDescription, listingDimensionX, listingDimensionY, listingDimensionZ, listingImage from listing where listingStatus=1
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:986)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:593)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:590)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:61)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:46)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1443)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1382)
        at com.example.shareandcare.listingHelper.getAllConfirmed(listingHelper.java:31)
        at com.example.shareandcare.admin.onCreate(admin.java:33)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7825)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7814)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1306)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930) 
2020-02-10 00:24:06.814 12602-12602/com.example.shareandcare I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 12602 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Uninstall the app from the device and rerun.

Comment: I did that but it doesn't work, I'm using a pixel3a XL

Comment: If you added the column after you first ran the app then onCreate() will not be executed because the database already exists. So you have to delete the database by uninstalling. Maybe you have in the Manifest this attribute set: `android:allowBackup="true"`. Set it to `false`, run, uninstall and rerun.

Comment: I did it like you said and I got it working, I'm trying to set your comment as the answer but I can't find anything that'll let me do that

Comment: It's fine. This is a question that has been asked and answered multiple times before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL code for create and drop table looks valid. There is a line in your logcat-log: "no such column" which means your "getAllConfirmed" is executet but your migration is not working, so keep an eye on this:

1. Increment the version number of your database, maybe your upgrade script is not executed (So just increment the "2" to "3" in your super constructor call)
2. If this is not working, you can just uninstall the app from the device/emulator, like forpas mentioned in the comment.
3. Set a breakpoint and see if the create table/upgrade command was executed

In general, if you want to add a column, it is better to just ALTER the table and add the column. But I guess you are just at the beginning of your app and you would like to keep things more easy, so your method is valid as long you haven't released your app.

If you just started, I just want let you know, Android has introduced a new way for db creation, which is more common and simple:

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room

This does not fix your problem, but if you are able to upgrade, this would simplify the db creation of your project

Answer (score 0):

Just to add, always add a null checker so as to prevent App Crashes.

A simple:

```
if (null) {
 return "";
}

would go a long way
```